# How can I use list values to format an API payload request string?

Tags: python, list, python-requests

I'm trying to make multiple look-ups using an API using a list in order to create a dictionary that I can then manipulate a dataframe with. I am currently using ({}.format(i)), which runs, however I receive a warning from the API that there is an invalid format for the required field.

When I test the code by hand typing one of the list values in place of ({}.format(i)), it works, so I 'm fairly sure it's related to using ({}.format(i)), however, not sure of another way to do this.

I've included an example of the code below. Is it the " being escaped by the backslash? Thanks for any help!

```
list_string = ['XXXXXX','YYYYYY','ZZZZZZ']

for i in list_string
    url = "https://fakeurl.api.co.uk/enquiry"
    payload = "{\n\t\"identification1\": \"({}.format(i))\"\n}" # Works when ({}.format(i)) replaced with XXXXXX
    headers = {
      'x-api-key': 'INSERT KEY HERE',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
    response = response.json()
    response
```

Comment: I think you meant `payload = "{\n\t\"identification1\": \"({})\"\n}".format(i)`

Comment: When I try the configuration you mention @PaulM., I receive the following error: KeyError: '\n\t"identification1"'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `format` call needs to be added at the end of the string, like the following. Also, `list` is a reserved word in Python, please use a different one. And, you need to escape the outer curly braces.

EDIT: Removed brackets after adding additional curly braces.

```
list_string = ['XXXXXX','YYYYYY','ZZZZZZ']

for i in list_string:
    url = "https://fakeurl.api.co.uk/enquiry"
    payload = "{{\n\t\"identification1\": \"{}\"\n}}".format(i)
    headers = {
      'x-api-key': 'INSERT KEY HERE',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
    response = response.json()
    response
```

Comment: Having the format call at the end of the string results in: KeyError: '\n\t"identification1"'. Also, understood that list is a reserved word, I understood list_string should be okay?

Comment: Please try my latest edit. It should work.

Comment: The problem was with the extra curly braces, that need to be escaped by duplicating them when using string formatting { -> {{ and } -> }}

Comment: Ah! So escaping the curly braces allows the code to complete, however, I am still receiving the `Invalid format for field` from the API response. When I tested by removing `.format(i)` and replacing `({})` with `XXXXXX` I receive the same error. Then when I remove the escaping curly braces, it works. Thanks for your help with looking into this.

Comment: My feeling is that something is preventing `XXXXXX` from being reproduced as exactly `XXXXXX` when using the list or .format call... I'm very new to using APIs, but could this be a way of stopping people using lists to avoid high numbers of lookups? (this is an open source, UK government-provided API)

Comment: Solved! By removing the `()` from `({})'. Have edited your answers Don Charlie - Thanks!